# Solving PDE on manifold via Hodge theory

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

Let $(M, g)$ be a Riemannian manifold, where $M$ is compact without boundary. The Hodge decomposition tells us that

$$\Omega^k = \ker (\Delta) + \text{Im} \ d + \text{Im}\ d^* . $$

Note that we can use that to solve the Poisson equation: there exists a smooth function $u$ solving $\Delta u = g$ if and only if $\int_M gd\mu = 0$.

To see why, note that the hypothesis on $g$ and the Hodge decomposition shows that $-g = d^* \beta$ for some one form $\beta$. Use Hodge decomposition again, write $\beta = \beta_1 + d u + d^* \alpha$. Then 
$$g  = -d^*\beta = -d^* d u = \Delta u . $$

So the argument is quite simple. Now if we have a vector fields $X$ on $M$ and consider the PDE

$$ \Delta u + \nabla_X u + g = 0, $$

can we formulate a statement similar as above (that is, such a $u$ exists iff some integrability conditions on $X$, $g$ are satisified?)